# Show CheckBox on ToolStripButton

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, toolstrip, toolstripbutton

I know that the `ToolStripButton` has checkbox functionality and should be used when you need a checkbox on a `ToolStrip`. However, the blue outline that appears to be the only indication of being `Checked` doesn't exactly scream "Hey, this is a checkbox!" to users. I could have sworn that I had previously found a way to get a `ToolStripButton` to show a checkbox in lieu of an image before, but apparently I deleted that instance after I decided on a different UI scheme for what I needed it for then; and I can't for the life of me seem to figure out how I got it working before.

Maybe all I did was add an image of a check; however, I would expect that my Resources would still have an image that I used for an unchecked state if that were the case. Is there any way to get a `ToolStripButton` to show an actual checkbox without resorting to making it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own component inheriting `ToolStripControlHost` that hosts a `CheckBox` control.  That's exactly what the `ToolStripComboBox`, `ToolStripProgressBar` and `ToolStripTextBox` components do for `ComboBox`, `ProgressBar` and `TextBox` controls.

Comment: I see that somebody has downvoted your answer, and I am curious if they or anybody else might be willing or able to supply a reason.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing myself. Maybe because it doesn't answer directly the question of how to get a `ToolStripButton` to display a check box but it wouldn't be an actual `CheckBox` control in that case anyway.